# automake-1.13: command not found

Tags: apache, automake, apache2.4

I was try to install Apache 2.4.

This requires apr, apr-util and pcre.

I was trying to configure pcre. I use the below command inside pcre directory :

$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/httpd*/srclib/pcre/

after this,

$ make

Output is like this :

cd . && /bin/sh /usr/httpd-2.4.9/srclib/pcre-8.33/missing automake-1.13 --gnu Makefile
/usr/httpd-2.4.9/srclib/pcre-8.33/missing: line 81: automake-1.13: command not found
WARNING: 'automake-1.13' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'Makefile.am' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'automake' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         http://www.gnu.org/software/automake

make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 127

I tried configuring automake 1.13, but it didn't worked for me and I do not have permission to do something in root directory.

Please help !

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's odd: it shouldn't be looking for a hard-coded name like "automake-1.13" ... especially if you've run "./configure".  SUGGESTION: do a "yum install automake*" (or apt-get install automake*") and see what happens.

Comment: This looks like automatic rebuilding of the Makefile due to timestamp skew, either when the source was created or when you unpacked it. Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5745366/384593) solve this for you?

Comment: how did you get Apache in the first place? This types of error also come when you copy Apache source from other source folder instead of directly extracting it from tar provided by Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround here: https://github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig/issues/22

Run these so to keep the executables that are being issues from running:

make AUTOCONF=: AUTOHEADER=: AUTOMAKE=: ACLOCAL=:

make install AUTOCONF=: AUTOHEADER=: AUTOMAKE=: ACLOCAL=:

I'm still having issues with the pcre-config but I'm pretty sure that's network time issue for me.