# 'make' command goes run ./configure

Tags: makefile, autotools, multiple-makefiles

So, i compile apt from source code, i need running `./configure` before running `make`. But why, when run `make` command, it's goes running `./configure`. Why that's running `./configure` when i running `make`? Because `make` reconfigure it?

### Note

I see an multiple `Makefile` file in apt source code folder.

```sh
root@localhost:~/oneos/apt-1.2.32# ls
AUTHORS                    apt-private    environment.mak
COMPILING                  bin            ftparchive
COPYING                    build          include
COPYING.GPL                buildlib       makefile
Dockerfile                 cmdline        methods
Makefile                   completions    mirror-failure.py
README.SrvRecords          config.log     obj
README.make                config.status  po
README.md                  configure      prepare-release
README.progress-reporting  configure.ac   scripts
abicheck                   debian         shippable.yml
aclocal.m4                 doc            test
apt-inst                   docs           vendor
apt-pkg                    dselect
root@localhost:~/oneos/apt-1.2.32#
```

Comment: The directory listing you present appears to show that Apt has a build system based on the GNU Autotools, though there are one or two inconsistencies.  Makefiles built via the Autotools contain rules to rebuild the build system and / or re-`configure` when build-system components are (or seem to be) out of date.  Not enough information is provided to diagnose this case in any detail, however.  We would need a [mre] for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [autotools: force make not to rebuild configure/Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731023/autotools-force-make-not-to-rebuild-configure-makefile)